# GCC not standard / non-conforming optimization flags?

Tags: gcc, optimization, compilation, clang, llvm

I'm looking for compiler optimization flags that disregard standards compliance to produce better performing/smaller binaries.

Thus far I found:

```
-ffast-math
    -fno-math-errno
    -funsafe-math-optimizations
        -fno-signed-zeros
        -fno-trapping-math
        -fassociative-math
        -freciprocal-math
    -ffinite-math-only
    -fno-rounding-math
    -fno-signaling-nans
    -fcx-limited-range
    -fexcess-precision=fast

-fmerge-all-constants
```

Are there more of this type of flags?

Comment: `-fsingle-precision-constant` might help for programs using mostly single-precision. Aliasing is something that often make C/C++ slower than Fortran but it looks like there is no way to assume there is no aliasing between function parameters of the same type in C/C++ using GCC/Clang (`-fstrict-aliasing` is not enough).

Answer (score 0):

[`-Ofast`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-Ofast) should exactly do this.

Comment: In particular, `-Ofast` also mentions enabling `-fallow-store-data-races`.